# Entity framework adds 2 milliseconds to a date attribute, why?

Tags: entity-framework

Why does Entity Framework add 2 milliseconds to a date attribute

```
foreach (var msg in msgs)
           {
               msg.Status = (int)StaticsParams.MessageStatus.Deleted;
               msg.LastUpdate = deletedDate;
               rep.Update(msg);
           }

           rep.UnitOfWork.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Do you mean why does it take 2ms to complete the action or that your date-time stamp is 00.02 ?

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking for.

Comment: Is your server moving around with almost light speed?

Comment: @MohamedHrichi, you haven't demonstrated the error. I can't try this code out if you don't say which libraries you're using. You need to provide more information. Where did you get the UnitOfWork library? How do you determine that 2ms has been added to a date?

Comment: thank you the problem is in sql server, I changed the type to datetime2 and it's working

Comment: Mohamed: you should add your fix as an answer and mark it as a solution, so it's easier for visitors to find. I was having the same problem in one of my integration tests